# Open cart footer.twig file changes not reflecting

Tags: php, html, opencart

I am working on a site http://www.lemongrasshouse.com.au/ i am changing code inside `/public_html/lemongrasshouse.com.au/catalog/view/theme/lemongrasshouse/template/common/footer.twig`

but its not affecting the site.
Can anyone help me in this matter

Thanks

Somdeb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you also edited that twig file via the built in editor in Design > Theme Editor? If so, it will use that one (which is stored in the database) rather than the file itself.

Comment: Thanks Bro Its working